# archive tar minitar issue in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am using ruby 1.9 on windows server. I'm using archive/tar/minitar to
untar .tar file of size 45MB.

following code:

```
Minitar.unpack("../Data/#{@circle_name}/#{@process_date}/#{@process_time}/#{ip_Dir}/#{enb_tar_file_name}","../Data/#{@circle_name}/#{@process_date}/#{@process_time}/#{ip_Dir}")
```

when code is called from command prompt it is working file,takes few
seconds.
but from windows scheduler it is taking more than 10 minutes some times
1 hour to untar the same file.

Anybody has idea of the problem?

Comment: Interesting. What is the system load (CPU, disk) in both cases?

Comment: CPU load 50% and disk load 38%

Comment: Is that in both cases? I meant to find out whether the load is equal or differs substantially. The latter could mean that Windows Scheduler executes the task with minimum amount of resources so that the impact on the system is not noticeable.

Comment: in both cases CPU and Memory load is same. But it is taking time differently in both cases.